# Update existing data Json with ajax post request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, xmlhttprequest

I have a data.json. With GET request i put it in my index.html

```js
// example of data
//  "Rule": [
//        {
//          "Name": "rule 1",
//          "RulebookID": 2,
//          "RuleId": 72,
//          "ID": "assotiated"
//        },
//        {
//          "Name": "rule 2",
//          "RulebookID": 1,
//          "RuleId": 92,
//          "ID": "available"
//        },
      
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://localhost:3000/Main',
  type: 'GET',
  headers: { accept: 'application/json;odata=verbose;' },
})
  .done(rules)
  .fail((jqXHR, status, errorThrown) => {
    console.log(`problem loading data: ${errorThrown}`);
  });
  
  function rules(data) {
  data.Rule.forEach((obj) => {
    $('#availableRules').append(
            `<div class="form-check" id="${obj.ID}">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"
                value="${obj.RuleId}" id="${obj.RuleId}"/>
              <label class="form-check-label" for="${obj.RuleId}">GDPR${obj.RulebookID} - ${obj.Name}</label>
            </div>`,
  });
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="checkboxes" id="availableRules">
  </div>
</div>
```

then, when user manipulate with site, on changeId button click - div.form-check changing id to 'available'

```js
$('#changeId').click(() => {
  const p = $('#availableRules .form-check-input').parent('div').detach();
  p.attr('id', 'available');
  $('#availableRules').append(p);
});
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="changeId">Change id</button>
```

How to handle this event and update Only Rule.ID value with ajax POST/PUT request and leave the same all another data?

Comment: its replacing whole .form-check to another div

Comment: main question is how to update only needed value and left the same all others with ajax post/put request

Comment: updated a question, thank you!

Comment: How exactly is that single button related to your multiple fields?

Comment: it's moving div.form-check to another div and changing .form-check id to available. All i need is update new id in data.json after changing id

Comment: So it is intentional that the single button should target multiple form-check-input?  Also, your click logic doesn't move the elements to a different div.  It detaches them (they're already in the #availableRules div), and after changing them, appends them back to the same #availableRules element.

Answer (score 0):

When creating rule items, you may set ids which includes Rule.ID (ex:

```
itemHtml = `<span id="rule_${Rule.ID}>...</span>`
```

On response from back end, just select every item by ID and update innerHtml/value/style.

```
responseItems.forEach((item) => { $("#rule_"+item.ID).html = ...
```